# Need to reset password. I can login the computer with fingerprint

Tags: windows, passwords

Win 10. I forgot my password. I can still login the computer using fingerprint everyday ( I am typing this question using this computer now), but I need to find out my password in case.

The current user (local user, not Microsoft account) is the only account

In this situation, what is the good way to reset my password, without loosing data in the system?

I tried created a new admin account; but when I got into that account, got to the Accounts, I can delete the current account, but I can't reset the password of it.

Thoughts?

Comment: Open command prompt and type net user <user> <new_password>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on your "My Computer, Computer, This PC" (depending on your windows version) and open Manage.

Then navigate to Local Users & Groups, right click on your user account and click Set Password and there you are setting new password without knowing your current password.

Answer (score 1):

When I was in new admin account, in the "Settings" App, it was now allowed to change another account's password.

Then I went back and forth, found that in the "Control Panel" App (different from the "Settings"), when "Manage another account", changing another account's password is working.

Viola!

Answer (score 0):

Login system, create a new admin account and remember its password.

Login this new admin account, press Win+X(right-click start menu button), choose Computer Management, navigate to Local user sand Groups, Users, find out the user account which your forget password.

Right-click account and select Set Password.

[image]

Done.